# Kubernetes on AWS EC2 - Modify --max-pods in scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

We are running containers on Kubernetes on Amazon AWS. This cluster was created via the kube-up set of scripts. Everything was provisioned correctly and working fine. We ran into a snag however - our fairly large servers, c4.xlarges, are only allowed to run 40 pods. This is a small number for us, as we are running many small pods, some rarely used. Is there a way to up this limit from the salt master or the launch configuration? What is the best route to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! I think I made a pretty good fix too, from what I can tell. I'm new to Salt, but feel I have a pretty decent grasp on it now. It's much simpler and less intimidating than I thought, a really neat tool. Anyway, onto the fix:

Kubernetes provisions the master and the minions with salt. Salt's config files are located at `/srv/salt`. After looking at the `top.sls` file, I found the `kubelet` folder (we need to change the flags passed to the kubelet). Poking through that folder we find the `init.sls` file, pointing to the `kubelet.service` file that is using the `salt://kubelet/default` for the config. Perfect, that's just the `/srv/salt/kubelet/default` file. Yuck. Lots of mega conditionals, but it all boils down to that last line `DAEMON_ARGS=...` If we want to do this the right way, modify the last line to add another variable:

```
{% set max_pods =  "--max-pods=" + pillar.get('kubelet_max_pods', '40') %}

DAEMON_ARGS="{{daemon_args}} {{api_servers_with_port}} {{debugging_handlers}} {{hostname_override}} {{cloud_provider}} {{config}} {{manifest_url}} --allow_privileged={{pillar['allow_privileged']}} {{pillar['log_level']}} {{cluster_dns}} {{cluster_domain}} {{docker_root}} {{kubelet_root}} {{configure_cbr0}} {{cgroup_root}} {{system_container}} {{pod_cidr}} {{max_pods}}"
```

(Notice our new variable max_pods)

This config file has access to our pillar files, the "config" files of salt. These are located right next to the salt configs in  `/srv/pillar`. After verifying all these configs are passed to all hosts, we can modify one. I thought it best fit in `cluster-params.sls`:

```
kubelet_max_pods: '80'
```

I killed off my old nodes and now our nodes have a max of 80 pods per host instead of the default.